# Apache POI for Excel: Setting the cell type to "text" for an entire column

Tags: excel, xls, apache-poi, xlsx

I need to generate an .xls (Excel) file, using the Java library [Apache POI for spreadsheets](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).

The file will contain a list of phone numbers in column A, formatted as "0221...." or "+49221..." - so Excel by default interprets them as numeric cells. This is bad, because the leading 0 or + will get trimmed.

To solve the problem, I can use `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)`, which works fine, but only for the specific cells I set this for.

How can I apply this setting for the entire column (i.e. even for all the remaining cells, where the user will enter additional phone numbers)?

*In Excel, this is possible*: Selecting the entire column, and apply the cell type (the setting survives saving/loading the file.)

But I can't find the correct method for POI.

- First I assumed, it should be something like `sheet.setDefaultCellType(int colNum)`. But I can't find anything like this (probably I'm just blind? There are lots of [similar methods](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setDefaultColumnStyle%28int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle%29)  in the library for applying text styles like "align center" etc.)
- Then I thought: Maybe it can only be applied to a [NamedRange](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges) or something similar, but I haven't managed to work out how this works...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Will [this](http://osdir.com/ml/user-poi.apache.org/2011-04/msg00066.html) help?

> By creating a data format with the @ symbol and using that in a CellStyle
>   object that is then passed to the setDefaultColumnStyle() method, it was
>   possible to set the default data type of the column to, in this case, text.
>   I have not experiemented further but do suspect it would be possible to do
>   something similar with other style objects to set the default type to
>   numeric or even a customised format such as currency.

Comment: That looks good! As soon as I get back to the project, I will try this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I did the same.   
var cllstyl = this.Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
var currDataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat();         
cllstyl.DataFormat = currDataFormat.GetFormat("@");
sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(1, cllstyl); But it is not showing "Text" format, instead it shows "Date". Please help me on this.

Answer (score 26):

Here's some example code inspired by Vlad's answer:

```
DataFormat fmt = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
textStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
worksheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, textStyle);
```

The above code sets the default style for the first column of *worksheet* to *TEXT*.

Thanks, Vlad!

Answer (score 2):

A better way to set it now using POI is to use the `BuiltinFormats` class.

**Eg:**

To convert the column type to numeric

```
 CellStyle numericStyle = workbook.createCellStyle(); 
 numericStyle.setDataFormat(BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(2)); // 2 For Number 
 worksheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(colId, numericStyle);
```

The complete list of `BuiltinFormats` formats can be seen, [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html)

Answer (score 0):

Vlad:
This got most of the problem done. I found that all the empty rows were formatted the way I wanted them. However rows where I had initial zeros looked and worked fine; however if I had to change a pre-existing value with another value starting with zero the zeroes disappeared.  So I recommend adding code to when you create the value in the cell to reset the the setCellStyle to text.  here are some snippets:
  method public Cell createCell(Row r!, BBjNumber cell, BBjString value!)

```
c!=#this!.createCell(r!, cell)
c!.setCellValue(value!)
c!.setCellStyle(#text_format!)
```

methodret c!

```
#text_format! = #wb!.createCellStyle()
#text_format!.setDataFormat(#format!.getFormat("@"))
```

methodend

this may help some other sole searching for initial zeroes.
Thank you for posting.
Alex