# Applying price and percentage formatting in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi

Java 8 and Apache POI 4.1.x here.

The expected "cell formatting behavior" of Excel, as I've gathered from being an Excel user for most of my life, is as follows:

- There appears to be an underlying "*internal value*" of a cell, and then there is the "*visualization*" of that value
- The internal value is a number, value, etc. that is the actual/real value of that cell
- The visualization is an **optional** way of representing the internal value to the end user

  - Example: The internal value of a cell might be `0.678261`, but the cell might be formatted to handle decimals as percentages with hundredths-place precision, and so the end user might see that cell represented as `67.83%`. But if they were to use it in a formula, or modify its value, the underlying value of `0.678261` is what would be used/modified

**I'm trying to figure out how to do the same with POI.**

Meaning, I would like to use POI's API to write an internal value to a cell, but then configure that cell to (visually) represent the value with a different formatting applied.

My two use cases are:

1. Representing a numeric/decimal as a valid price (e.g. visually representing `203.9483495949` as `$203.95` to the end users, or `0.8375733` as `$0.84`); and
2. Representing a numeric/decimal as a valid percentage (e.g. visually representing `0.009383484` as `1.00%` to the end users, or `0.53282` as `53.28%`)

Currently I'm writing these values as follows:

```
BigDecimal validPrice = BigDecimal.valueOf(203.9483495949);
BigDecimal validPct = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.53282);

Row nextRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

nextRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(validPrice.doubleValue());
nextRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(validPct.doubleValue());
```

But when I write the data to an Excel file, I just see those same raw/internal values visualized (`203.9483495949` and `0.53282` respectively) in the columns, and I have to **manually** set formatting on them after I open the files up. Instead, rather than forcing end users to apply this formatting manually, I'd like POI to apply the formatting in the code, so that when the files are opened, they are formatted as `$203.95` and `53.28%` aleady.

Any idea as to how to do this?

Comment: You could build the `String`. You could also use a NumberFormatter and/or StringFormatter. All this show be done before or while setting the value. `BigDecimal` should have rounding capabilities. `"$" + validPrice.round(2).doubleValue()` and `validPct.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).round(2).doubleValue() + "%"`. I don't know if the code is correct. I wrote it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @Sedrick (+1) but I don't think you're understanding my question. The problem isn't with `BigDecimal` (as `BigDecimals` can represent just about anything number-related). The problem is that I want to know how to leverage the POI API to behave the way Excel already does: having an internal value and then a formatted ("visual") value displayed to the end user.

Comment: Have you tried ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/q/6510012/2423906

Comment: How should `0.009383484` be shown as `1.00%`? It will be shown as `0,94%` in `Excel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [Quick-guide - DataFormats](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats) you need using cell styles to format numbers in `Excel` cells having special number format.

Those `CellStyle`s are on workbook level and can be created as needed as shown in above linked examples. But you should not create exactly the same `CellStyle` multiple times as there are [limits for unique cell formats/cell styles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) in `Excel`.

The more flexible way is using [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html).  There:

> The various methods that deal with style's allow you to create your
>   CellStyles as you need them. When you apply a style change to a cell,
>   the code will attempt to see if a style already exists that meets your
>   needs. If not, then it will create a new style. This is to prevent
>   creating too many styles.

Using this we can create a structure which holds data objects per row and cell and a structure which holds data formats per column.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelFormattedValues {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();

  // structure which holds data objects per row and cell 
  Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
   new Object[]{"Price", "Percent"},
   new Object[]{203.9483495949, 0.53282},
   new Object[]{0.8375733, 0.009383484}
  };

  // structure which holds data formats per column
  short currencyDataFormat = format.getFormat("$#,##0.00");
  short percentDataFormat = format.getFormat("0.00%");
  short[] dataFormats = {currencyDataFormat, percentDataFormat};

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row;
  int firstRow = 1; // first row is second row
  int r = 0; // loop variable for row
  Cell cell;
  int firstCol = 1; // first column is column B
  int c = 0; // loop variable for column
  for (Object[] dataRow : data) {
   row = sheet.createRow(firstRow + r);
   c = 0;
   for (Object dataValue : dataRow) {
    cell = row.createCell(firstCol + c);
    CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormats[c]);
    if (dataValue instanceof String) {
     cell.setCellValue((String)dataValue);
    } else if (dataValue instanceof Double) {
     cell.setCellValue((Double)dataValue);
    }
    c++;
   }
   r++;
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```